# Redirect only home page to another site. not sub pages. example.com to newsite.com using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect home page alone. But not the sub links. I tried with the following code, but it not works.

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[/]?
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/+[/]?
   RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

So my requirement is,

When user access : `http://test.site.co.uk` then should redirected to `http://newsite.co.uk`

When user access : `http://test.site.co.uk/mypage` then should redirected to `http://newsite.co.uk/mypage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter Version

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://newsite.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following rewrite rule :-

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example.com(\/{0,1})){1}$
RewriteRule http://example2.com(\/{0,1}) [R=301,L]
```

That (/{0,1}) part is for matching both example.com and example.com/ (but nothing esle) - if you do not wish to match example.com/ remove that part from both rows.